# How I can bring the space in this encrypted code

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to do encryption and decryption code. This code for encryption - >

```
              String text="I love StackOverflow";
              key="love";

              String s=text.toLowerCase();;
              String s1=key.toLowerCase();;
              char key1[];
              key1=new char[s1.length()];
              for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
               {
              key1[i]=s1.charAt(i);
               }
              int k[]=new int[key1.length];
              char c[]=new char[s.length()];
              int cc[]=new int [s.length()];
              //int r[]=new int[s.length()];
              int ss[]=new int[s.length()];
              char result[]=new char[s.length()];
               for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
               {
               c[i]=s.charAt(i);
               cc[i]=(int)c[i]-97;
               }
               for(int i=0;i<key1.length;i++)
               {
               k[i]=(int)key1[i]-97;
               }
              String g;
              for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
               {
               ss[i]=(k[i%s1.length()]+cc[i])%26;
               result[i]=(char)(ss[i]+97);
              }
              g=String.copyValueOf(result);
              label.setText(g.toUpperCase());
            }
```

It's giving me this result -- > THGSGSOWEOXOZJZVQZJA
And , when I am run decrypt message its give me-- > ITLOVETSTACKOVERFLOW  (But I want --> I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW) Problem with not getting space -- >
My decryption code is below

```
             String text2="THGSGSOWEOXOZJZVQZJA";
            text2=text2.toLowerCase();
            String key="love";
            String s=text2;
            String s1=key;
            char h[]=new char[s.length()];
            int hh[]=new int[s.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            {
                h[i]=s.charAt(i);
                hh[i]=h[i];
                hh[i]=(int)hh[i]-97;
            }
            char k[]=new char[s1.length()];
            int kk[]=new int[s1.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
            {
                k[i]=s1.charAt(i);
                kk[i]=k[i];
                kk[i]=(int)kk[i]-97;
            }
            int re1[]=new int[s.length()];
            char ref[]=new char[s.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            {
                re1[i]=hh[i]-kk[i%s1.length()];
            }
                String value;
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            {
                if(re1[i]<0)
                {
                    re1[i]=re1[i]+26;
                }
                    ref[i]=(char) (re1[i]+97);
             }
               value=String.copyValueOf(ref);
            // t2.setText(g);
             label_1.setText(value.toUpperCase());
```

Any idea how i can get the space or how i can detect it 
Did i ask the question two stupid that's why i got negative in my question ? I think it is hard enough for u guys :P

Comment: What do you think that % 26 is doing?

Comment: %26 is using because i follow auto key cipher from the tabuler form, i only counting the letter which is detected by ascii character , i mean only 26 character of alphabet

Comment: Most likely your question got downvoted because a) your code is not formatted properly. b) its not clear what you even want / what the actual constraints are. c) You made no attempt to write proper English so its hard to read. d) Its a simple problem with a simple solution but presented as if it were complicated. e) Did I mention that its hard to read your code?

Comment: I already mention that what is the problem i am facing, hey dude it is not easy solution, look i gave example output also in my question,

Answer (score 1):

I sure hope that this is primary a thought exercise of yours and you [don't plan to roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/42080) algorithm.

The problem is that you filter out spaces :)

If you increase the `%26` and the corresponding `+26` to `32` (the ascii for Space) it works fine.

Comment: You won me over at the first sentence.

Comment: Ya, the crypto table was given by the lecturer, we have to come out with the coding

Comment: Yes, if i use 32 its able to remove the space but i am limited only 26 english letter , I think i mention it before -  Vigenere table auto key cipher,

Comment: 26 characters does not include a space. So, how do you think this could work? In all seriousness. Either you have 26chars + space or you don't have spaces. In fact, why on earth should one want to limit this to only letters? There are punctuation, braces, parenthesis and there are non-english texts (and even in English é is a valid character)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment, I got another better solution for that, in java there have function where we can replace specific charater which string.replaceAll(" ","")  i did not get the space yet but i got the exact message with space

Comment: @JahidulIslam the function you noted removes spaces. Your question was how to preserve them. If you had a different goal altogether you should have said so.